# t-vim: MTXrun using extra quotes

Tags: context, mactex, t-vim

I'm trying to use the t-vim module for context installed from the TexLive 2010 basic package for Mac.

The problem I'm running into is that MTXrun tries to quote too much when calling vim, for example:

```
vim "-u NONE -e -C -n -c \\\"set tabstop=8\\\" -c \\\"syntax on\\\" -c \\\"set syntax=ruby\\\" -c \\\"let contextstartline=1\\\" -c \\\"let contextstopline=0\\\" -c \\\"source /usr/local/texlive/2010basic/texmf-dist/tex/context/third/vim/2context.vim\\\" -c \\\"wqa\\\" \\\"a-vimsyntax.tmp\\\" "
```

The command I used to compile the tex file was "context" without any arguments.

Thanks in advance.

---

### Code Used

```
\usemodule[vim]

\starttext
\definevimtyping [RUBY] [syntax=ruby]
\startRUBY
#! /usr/bin/ruby
# This is my first ruby program
puts "Hello World"
\stopRUBY
\stoptext
```

### Full Log

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/322145/

Comment: Can you add the input you used as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to solve it!

The t-vim.tex file at,

```
/usr/local/texlive/2010basic/texmf-dist/tex/context/third/vim
```

uses the following system command,

```
{mtxrun --verbose --noquote bin:vim
      "-u NONE  % No need to read unnessary configurations
       -e       % run in ex mode
       -C       % Set compatibile
       -n       % No swap
%      -V10log  % For debugging only, will go away later.
       -c \shellescapedquote set tabstop=\@@vstab \shellescapedquote\space    
       -c \shellescapedquote syntax on\shellescapedquote\space 
       -c \shellescapedquote set syntax=\@@vssyntax\shellescapedquote\space
       -c \shellescapedquote let contextstartline=\@@vsstart\shellescapedquote\space
       -c \shellescapedquote let contextstopline=\@@vsstop\shellescapedquote  \space
       -c \shellescapedquote source kpse:2context.vim\shellescapedquote\space
       -c \shellescapedquote wqa\shellescapedquote\space    
        \shellescapedquote#1\shellescapedquote\space "}
```

as you can see, it is using --noquote instead of --noquotes. Just add "s" and the problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if the latest development version of `t-vim` works? For testing, copy `t-vim.tex`, `t-filter.tex`, and `2context.vim` from [here](https://github.com/adityam/filter) and place them in the same directory as your tex file.

Comment: Hi Aditya, my t-vim.tex version is 2008.07.15. But I managed to solve the problem. I would also upvote you if I could.

Comment: @Pedro: Now you can. ;-)

Comment: Already did :).